# I can't start Cassandra Server in Eclipse( Unknown Commitlog version 4)

Tags: eclipse, cassandra

I'm trying to run Cassandra in eclipse, but I'm getting this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown commitlog version 4Exception encountered during startup: Unknown commitlog version 4

at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.getMessagingVersion(CommitLogDescriptor.java:81)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:118)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:93)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:146)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:126)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:305)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:461)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:504)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a version mismatch - possibly from downgrading Cassandra[?]

What version of Cassandra are you using in eclipse? Also, did you have another version running *and sharing the same commitlogs*? It is likely you have commitlogs from one version of cassandra being read from another. (That was my experience.)

Adding the solution, as provided by @LyubenTodorov in the comments:

> To solve this either change your commitlog_directory or empty your current commitlog dir (default is /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog)

Comment: +1, To solve this either change your `commitlog_directory` or empty your current commitlog dir (default is `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`)

Comment: Right. I was using 2.1, but I had problems with it, so switched back to 2.0.2. Thanks for the pointer.